# What operators have been defined for the STL iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

I've really googled a lot, but I couldn't find an answer.

What operators has been overloaded for the STL iterators? i.e. `list<t>::iterator, vector<t>::iterator, etc`.

I know about these:

- `* - dereference operator`
- `++ - increment operator (both postfix and prefix)`

I don't know about more. So back to the original question: which operators are defined to stl iterators?

Comment: Depends on the [category of the iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Comment: This depends on what iterator you are talking about. A random access iterator has more operators (e.g. +/-) than a forward iterator.

Comment: Why did you google [the alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) rather than iterators?

Comment: @jrok Where can I see the operators list?

Comment: @user1798362 Try clicking on categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will depend of the category of the iterator : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/

- [input_iterator_tag](http://www.cplusplus.com/input_iterator_tag)
- [output_iterator_tag](http://www.cplusplus.com/output_iterator_tag)
- [forward_iterator_tag](http://www.cplusplus.com/forward_iterator_tag)
- [bidirectional_iterator_tag](http://www.cplusplus.com/bidirectional_iterator_tag)
- [random_access_iterator_tag](http://www.cplusplus.com/random_access_iterator_tag)

Or maybe it is more clear on this link : **http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator**

As suggested in comments, here is a little piece of the standard :

> **24.2.1 In general**
>
> 1. [...]This International Standard defines five categories of iterators, according to the operations defined on them: *input iterators*, *output iterators*, *forward iterators*, *bidirectional iterators* and *random access iterators*, as shown below :

```
Random Access -> Bidirectional -> Forward -> Input
                                          -> Output
```

For example Forward iterators satisfy all the requirements of input iterators.

> **24.2.2 Iterator**
>
> The Iterator requirements form the basis of the iterator concept taxonomy; every iterator satisfies the Iterator requirements. This set of requirements specifies **opearations for dereferencing and incrementing** an iterator. Most algorithms will require additional operations to read (24.2.3) or write (24.2.4) values, or to **provide a richer set of iterator movements**.

Like it is said the iterators have requirements that define the operations we can do on them.

Comment: So, ++it, it++, ==, != , *it , are the defined operators?

Comment: also `+=`, `-=`, `[]`, `<`, `>`,`->` etc... You can infer the operators that are defined from the expressions in "valid expressions" column.

Comment: @user1798362 and `->`.

Comment: @user1798362 It depends of the category of the iterator like we said. For example for the [random_access_iterator_tag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) there is more operator defines.

Comment: @jrok These operators are _only_ necessary for random access iterators (and most iterators probably aren't random access).

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud I need the iterators that associated with the containers.

Comment: @user1798362 Which container?  Iterators are categorized by the operations they support.  If you implement a new type of container, which operations are supported depends on what the container is capable of.

Comment: @user1798362 But which container ?? for example [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) use mainly random_access_iterator...

Comment: And the links here all seem pretty useless to me.  They describe particular classes in the standard, and not the requirements for user defined classes.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud The iterator for vector is `std::vector<>::iterator`, and it conforms to the requirements of a random access iterator.  It doesn't "use" `random_access_iterator` (which as far as I can tell doesn't exist as a class).

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes... It wasn't correct. I should have said that the `std::vector<>::iterator` are conforms to the requirements of the `random_access_iterator` concept. Thanks for pointing the error.

Comment: en.cppreference.com is fine to use as reference material, but for the definitive answer to this question and questions like it, you need to go to the Standard.

Comment: @JohnDibling You are right, I edited the post. Hope thoses part explain why there is differents operators in function of the iterators.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the type of iterator.  For a forward iterator (the
simplest), you need:

```
class ForwardIterator
{
public:
    typedef ... difference_type;    // usually ptrdiff_t
    typedef ... value_type;
    typedef ... pointer;            // usually value_type*
    typedef ... reference;          // must be value_type&
    typedef std::forward_iterator_tag iterator_category;

    //  advance...
    ForwardIterator& operator++();
    ForwardIterator operator++( int );
    //  access...
    reference operator*() const;
    pointer operator->() const;
    //  check for end...
    bool operator==( Iterator const& other ) const;
    bool operator!=( Iterator const& other ) const;
};
```

The `typedef` are necessary unless you specialize
`std::iterator_traits` for the iterator type.  They may be
provided by inheriting publically from `std::iterator` (which
provides the appropriate defaults for all except
`iterator_category` and `value_type`).

Bidirectional iterators also require the two `operator--`, and
random access iterators require a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list for the vector iterator here :
[Random Access Iterator operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/)

And for the list iterator here :
[Bidirectional Iterator operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/)

In short, (and not exhaustive) for the vector iterators there are also :

- the comparison operators (<, <=, ...)
- the arithmetic operators ( it1 + it2, it2 - it1, ... )

And for both list iterators and vector iterators :

- the equalities/inequalities test operators (it1 == it2, it1 != it2)

Comment: Rather use the cppreference.com site as given in the comments, it tends to provide a higher quality (and less errors)

Comment: I'm sorry but there was no answer/comment when I began to write my answer.

Comment: Presumably, he's _not_ implementing vector iterators or list iterators, since these are already part of the standard library.  He needs to know the functions (and typedefs) for generic iterators.